# php/jQuery check if username exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to create a system that checks if the selected username is already being used or not. I have come up with the following code.

```
function checkUsername(username,func){ 
    $.post("functions/checkUsername.php",{'username': username},function(data){ 
        if(data!='1'){ popup_alert('The username you selected already exists.','Username Exists','Close'); return false; }
        else{ window[func](); }
    });
}
```

checkUsername.php returns a 0 if the username exists and 1 if it is available.  I have run many tests on that.  My issue is that for some reason it is running the if statement before data is set.  I have inserted a alert(data) before the if statement and it pops up with a 1 after the popup_alert is created.

Comment: How did you find out that it runs before the data is set ? Did you try looking over with FireBug or something like it ?

Comment: It won't run before. That is the success callback. So that is a very wrong assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkUsername(username,callback){ 
    $.post("functions/checkUsername.php",{'username': username},function(data){ 
    callback && callback(data);      
    });
}

...

checkUsername(username,function(data) {
  if(data!='1'){ popup_alert('The username you selected already exists.','Username     Exists','Close'); return false; }
    else{ window[func](); }
});
```

or you can use $.ajax

```
function checkUsername(username,func){ 
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false, 
        data: {'username': username},
        url: 'functions/checkUsername.php',
        success: function(data) {
          if(data!='1'){ popup_alert('The username you selected already exists.','Username  Exists','Close'); return false; }
        else{ window[func](); }
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Connection error!');
        }
      });
}
```